# Why is [FromQuery] attribute required?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-2.0

I created an api with the following action:

```
[HttpGet("GetStuff/{Name}")]
public ActionResult<string> GetStuff([FromRoute]GetStuffModel requestModel)
{
    if (requestModel == null) return BadRequest();
    var result = doStuff();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

The model looks like this:

```
public class GetStuffModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double MyNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am using swagger to test this and basically the above doesn't work as I think it should. What happens is when I submit a get request with swagger and look at the values in the model, I find that only Name is captured. Latitude and Longitude have a value of 0. However, if I change the model to this:

```
public class GetStuffModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [FromQuery]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    [FromQuery]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double MyNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then everything gets captured. My question is why do I have to specify `[FromQuery]` when I have already declared `[FromRoute]` in the controller?

Edit: I also added `MyNumber` variable and that one also picks up without the need of `[FromQuery]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `[FromRoute]` attribute model binder tries to bind values from request route data. With the current setup route data contains only 1 value for `Name` (well, there also `action` and `controller` values there, but it doesn't matter now) so it's possible to bind only `Name` property of `GetStuffModel` (if you add `string Action` property to model you'll see it will be binded as well). When you add `[FromQuery]` attribute to model properties it overrides model binding behavior and allows to bind certain properties from query string. In this case swagger adds `Latitude` and `Longitude` as query parameters and binding works fine.

Comment: @Bojan Well, it doesn't work for me without `[FromQuery]` so you must have some additional config I'm not aware of

Comment: I think I figured out why and your explanation makes sense.